# Copy Server IP and add it before commands

Tags: sed, awk

Im trying to take a file that has the following output and make it show the site and the Commands needed ran on that site. Meaning. Basically i want to take the SiteID in this case Site1 and add it to the front of the commands that need to be ran on that site.

Current File

```
Site1
'command;command2;command3'
Site2
'command;command2;command3'
Site3
'command;command2;command3'
```

Expected output is:

```
Site1 'command;command2;command3'
Site2 'command;command2;command3'
Site3 'command;command2;command3'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -F\' 'NF==1{site=$0;next} {print site, $0}' file
Site1 'command;command2;command3'
Site2 'command;command2;command3'
Site3 'command;command2;command3'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this `sed`

```
sed -i.bak 'N;s/\n//g' yourfile.txt
```

From `man sed`:

-i [SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]

```
          edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
```

Comment: Yes this will be useful if you want to change the file in place

Answer (score 0):

Use the `paste` command

```
paste - - <file
```

And it you want a space as a delimiter do

```
paste -d ' ' - - <file
```

Or if you must use awk:

```
awk '{printf "%s"(NR%2?" ":"\n"), $0}' file
```

Or a bit shorter awk command:

```
awk '{ORS=(NR%2?" ":"\n")}1' file
```

Comment: The Awk works, but i think the when im trying to do is a bit more complicated, but basically im trying to copy the Site name to more then one line if possible. The Awk works until it hits a file that has more then one command line and then it messes up. On the files that have just one command like it works just find. so it would also need to not only move it in front of the line but duplicate it if their was more then one line.

Comment: @user1475436 Then you need to separate the "site" lines from the "command" lines. By what criterion do you decide to which type each line belongs to?